# Remove extra spaces between CardViews in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have several `CardView` in `RecyclerView` and I can't remove extra spaces between them.

My `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="HEAD"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="SUBHEAD"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_user_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/grey_bg" />
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRe78.png). Red arrow points to extra space.

Comment: Please show Recycler View code.

Comment: android:paddingBottom="8dp" try removing this from your relative layout..

Comment: @ShoebSiddique, sorry for late reply. I've added `RecyclerView` xml code.

Comment: @HourGlass, still have extra spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get rid of it all together you may use a negative for the contentPadding attribute of the CardView such as:

```
card_view:contentPadding="-8dp"
```

Adding negative margins should work.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed spaces, but I heard it's "ugly" solution.

Comment: yes, it is but dont have other options for this @MrAwesome

Comment: it reduce the cardsize not their spaces b/w them